# Tag point counter not working?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tag-badges, tag-score

I got my gold tag badge recently, but it seems like it is some kind of bug with the counter. When I look at my profile and hover with the mouse over the "1k" text to the left of the gold badge, it says that the total score is 1001. But when I count points I have received after the gold badge do know that I have received at least 16 points after I got the gold badge. Some of the answers have upvotes from almost a week ago, so it's definitely not the cache.

Is it some kind of bug?

EDIT:

Now, it shows 1009. Should it really take that long?

Comment: I looked at your profile and it indeed says `1001`. I upvoted an answer of yours - let's see if the counter updates. EDIT: interesting, I hovered over the score and got [this text](https://i.imgur.com/e1RVCSo.png). Something doesn't add up - questions have total score of 58 while answers have a total score of 1001

Comment: It's been more than an hour since I upvoted and there is no change to the score on your badge. I assume that perhaps [caching is not to blame](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) in this case, as updates to badge score are usually faster than this.

Comment: @VLAZ Some of the answers are from almost a week ago, so it's definitely not the cache.

Comment: @VLAZ tag scores only update once a day, so you’d have to wait a lot longer.

Comment: What is more interesting is that I can only see [478 qualifying answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6699433+%5Bc%5D+is%3Aa+wiki%3Ano&mixed=1), so 19 fewer than your tag page says you should have. It could be the deleted-after-60-days-with-score-of-3-or-up rule applies, however, but I see there’s only 1 of those.

Comment: Ah, no, I’m a numpty. The 19 “missing” are your questions, which are included in the numbers. In which case your stats look *exactly right*; the tag score reflects the net score (upvotes minus downvotes), not your reputation.

Comment: Looking over your recent rep changes you have, at most, gained 6 points on the c tag, most of those in the past 24 hours. If any of the questions you answered were also re-tagged then that easily accounts for the difference. Otherwise, werd are just a single 24 hour period behind on tag score calculations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's possible that I have done a mistake, but I did only count answers, and only the score, not rep.

Comment: Yes, it updates once a day, so it *does take that long*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, but If I'm not mistaken I'm talking about points that I got AFTER the gold badge but MORE than a day ago. Several days in fact.

Comment: You also lost a post (deleted) and got some downvotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see. Maybe you should write an answer? :)